# Каждый Фильтр намерений должен иметь один (и только один) тег action

Tags: android, activity, android-intent

> Каждый Фильтр намерений должен иметь один (и только один) тег action.

Какие выводы следуют из этого правила? Одно Активити - одно действие? Но ведь приложение может состоять из нескольких Активити и загрузка при этом прописывается с какото-то конкретного Активити.

Имеется ввиду, откроется нужный Активити в приложении минуя Загрузочный Активити или надо перенаправлять действие с Загрузочного на тот Активити, который выполнит действие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вопрос не очень понятен, но указанная вами цитата не запрещает использовать [несколько фильтров для одной активити](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13795834/3212712):

```
<activity android:name=".MyActivity">
  <intent-filter>
     <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
     <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
  </intent-filter>
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <data android:mimeType="text/html" />
  </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

При запуске к-л активити через конкретный интент запустит именно нужную активити. Т.е. никакие промежуточные/стартовые/главные активити запущены не будут (если вы сами это специально не пропишите).

Comment: а ну да, спасибо, сглупил конечно в понимании этой цитаты. Не подумал про несколько фильтров.

Comment: Обновил вопрос, может немного понятнее объяснил.

Comment: @TimurVI, Всё ещё не очень понятно, но ответ дополнил

Comment: то, что хотел узнать. С вопросом согласен, сумбурно как-то. Имелось ввиду увязать запуск Активити с конкретным действием и всем приложением, в котором по умолчанию, к примеру, по нажатию на иконку приложения, прописано другое Активити. Вы ответили на мой вопрос в общем.